# Displaying information in messagebox from listbox

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I am writing a program that requires me to select a home address from a listbox.  When i click on the display button a messagebox is supposed to appear and display the address and several other bits of information stored in an array list for that address.  I am fairly unfamiliar with listboxes and can't figure out how to display all this information in a messagebox from one selection in a listbox.

Comment: It's a web solution or windows ?

Comment: its a C# windows form application

Answer (score 2):

You can get the selected item value in a `ListBox`

```
string curItem = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

you may handle the `onClick` event of your btn, then show information in a message box

```
 MessageBox.Show (curItem );
```

More info for MessageBox [here](http://www.functionx.com/vcsharp/general/messagebox.htm)

Comment: I have a method called DisplayInfo() that sets up all the information in a column but i dont know how to call upon it for a selected index

Comment: handle the `SelectedIndexChanged` of the `ListBox`, you can use `listBox1.SelectedIndex`

Answer (score 0):

or you can write

```
MessageBox.Show(listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
```

no need to initialize any variable if you do not need th