# Selected index from listbox to messagebox

Tags: c#, winforms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Displaying information in messagebox from listbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10201226/displaying-information-in-messagebox-from-listbox)

I'm writing a program that requires the user to input seven different parameters for their house or apartment.  When the information is submitted the address entered goes into the listbox.  When the user clicks on a separate button the seven parameters should be displayed in a messagebox.  I already have a method called DisplayInfo() that has when called upon it will display the information in a column so i just need help with the selected index part of it.

```
public virtual string DisplayInfo()
{
  return string.Format("Property ID: {0}\nProperty Address: {1}\nYear Built: {2}\nNumber of Bedrooms: {3}\nSquare Footage: {4}\nPrice: {5}",
    GetID(),
    GetAddress(),
    GetYearBuilt(),
    GetBedrooms(),
    GetSquareFootage(),
    GetPrice());
}
```

Comment: Is this webforms or winforms ?

Comment: its a c# windows form application

Answer (score 3):

For a button, wire up the `Click` event:

```
public Form1() {
  InitializeComponent();
  button1.click += new EventHandler(button1_Click);
}

void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  if (listBox1.SelectedIndex > -1) {
    MessageBox.Show(DisplayInfo());
  }
}
```

Comment: for some reason, my DisplayInfo method doesnt show up?

Comment: @jamesclemens You have to show us your `DisplayInfo` method.  Oh, and learn to accept answers and vote on helpful posts.  See the [FAQ](http://www.stackoverflow.com/faq)

Comment: instead of having the code under the SelectedIndexChanged, shouldn't it be under the "Show apartment" button?

Comment: @jamesclemens Well, I can't see your program from here.  I see you edited your post with some code. Yes, move your `DisplayInfo` to your button's click event.  What your code is *not* showing is what all your functions are doing: `GetID()`, `GetAddress()`.  Those function presumably should be using the `listBox1.SelectedIndex` or `listBox1.SelectedItem` or `listBox1.SelectedValue` calls depending on how you setup your data.

Comment: this is what i had already but this just displays one messagebox after another not just the selected item.                                //private void AddApartmentToListBox()
        //{
        //    lstApartment.Items.Clear();
        //    foreach (Apartment persons in Home)
        //    {
        //        lstApartment.Items.Add(persons.GetAddress());
        //    }
        //}

Comment: Please don't post code snippets in comments.  I updated the answer to only show one MessageBox.  I don't know what your code snippet has to do with anything: you are clearing a ListBox and adding items to it.  I'm starting to get the feeling we are dealing with 7-8 listboxes and you are trying to get all of the selected items together into a single message.  Is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: Okay, here's whats going on.  I have six textboxes that apply to bot House and Apartment subclasses.  I then have a "furnished" option for apartment, and a "garage capacity" for house.  There are two listboxes that when you hit either "add house" or "add apartment" it will put the address of the property in the respective listbox.  The problem i'm having is that I have a button for each listbox("show apartment" and "show house").  The code i have now displays every property i input instead of just the selected one. Every time i try to call upon the DisplayInfo() method i get an error.

Comment: @jamesclemens "I get an error" seems to be the crux of the problem here, and you need to document what that error is.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(lbox.SelectedItem != null)
 {
    DisplayInfo(lbox.SelectedItem);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

hi on the selectedIndex change event method of listbox call your method of "DisplayInfo"

```
Protected Void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if(listBox1.SelectedIndex!=-1)
  { 
     DisplayInfo(listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
  }
}
```

Comment: for some reason the DisplayInfo() isn't an option?